# Hot Ti Insert Script In An ASP.NET Form On Run Time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-visualization, google-visualization, visual-web-developer

I am saving Visualizations in a database, title, description...etc and CODE field, in the Code field I save the "code" that will generate the visualization, it may be as simple as a URL for an image hosted somewhere, or something like:

```
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/gpub?url=http%3A%2F%2Foj0ijfii34kccq3ioto7mdspc7r2s7o9-ss-opensocial.googleusercontent.com%2Fgadgets%2Fifr%3Fup_title%3DBrands%26up_initialstate%26up__table_query_url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fspreadsheets.google.com%252Fspreadsheet%252Ftq%253Frange%253DA%25253AE%2526key%253D0AqFjLMbUaBn_dFhwbV9DQ3N6cWN1SmFiUlF5X1RXUkE%2526gid%253D0%2526pub%253D1%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Fig%252Fmodules%252Fmotionchart.xml%26spreadsheets%3Dspreadsheets&height=448&width=710"></script>
```

I am saving this as an nvarchar(max) in my database, now I have a page that should display the visualization I call on run time, so what is the best way to do so?! a div for example? and how?

Thanks in dvance

Comment: IFrame would be an option, as it takes care of loading URL's, and it does'nt crash your page even if the content URL doesnt exist.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how about more details for a newbie like me :P hahaha, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here you go Maen ...

1) Declare your IFrame (you can set more properties like height & width):

```
<IFRAME id="frame1" scrolling="auto" runat="server">
</IFRAME>
```

2) Get the URL from your "Script" stored in your Database

```
frame1.Attributes["src"] = DAL.GetURLPath();
```

does this help?

Comment: Didn't work, I got the following error:
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30545: Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Source Error:

Line 15:             Dim codeString As String = visualizationTable.Rows(0).Item("code").ToString()
Line 16: 
Line 17:             viewerIframe.Attributes["src"] = codeString
Line 18:

Comment: then did you try frame1.Attributes("src") = DAL.GetURLPath() ?

Comment: Even when I manually insert my code inside the src attribute to make sure its not about data retrieval, I still get an error that says:
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Line 7:  <iframe id = "viewerIframe" runat = "server" scrolling = "auto" src = "<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com.....</script>" ></iframe>

Comment: it works fine when my src is a URL for an image! but not when its a script!

Comment: you cannot nest quote tags(") in src. you need to use escape sequences. meaning, replace all occurence of (") within src with (""). something like src = "<script src=""spreadsheets.google.com.....</script>";

Comment: Also, you need to remove script. just say frame1.Attributes("src") ="https://spreadsheets.google.com....."

Comment: Will test and get back you you mate :)

Comment: This won't be too convenient as I want users to Copy Paste the script only!
I used a DIV as in:
 viewerDiv.InnerHtml = codeString
It worked perfectly for scripts, but when the codeString is just a URL it merely displays the URL on the screen!
I tried
<image id.... imageURL="URL....etc"/> but it just showed nothing

Comment: Solved now, I saved the image in HTML format rather than ASP, now I can inject scripts and normal images in the innerhtml part of the div ;)